# VCRUNTIME140.dll não foi encontrado ao rodar executável do cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

Há alguns dias atrás eu desenvolvi uma aplicação em Python e gerei um executável utilizando o pacote **cx_freeze** com o seguinte código:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 

setup(
    name = "Minha Aplicação",
    version = "",
    description = "",
    executables = [Executable("app.py", base = "Win32GUI")]
)
```

Na minha máquina, tanto a aplicação em script **.py** como o executável funcionam perfeitamente, mas resolvi testar na máquina de um amigo para ter certeza. Quando meu amigo executou o programa, foi apresentado o seguinte erro para ele:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu pesquisei na internet sobre e algumas pessoas diziam para adicionar ao parâmetro `options` a configuração `'include_msvcr': True` para que a DLL seja adicionada, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
setup(
    name = "Keylogger",
    version = "",
    description = "",
    executables = [Executable("keylogger.py", base = "Win32GUI")],
    option = {'build_exe': {'include_msvcr': True}}
    )
```

Mesmo adicionando essa configuração, o programa não funciona no computador do meu amigo e eu tenho quase certeza de que esse erro não é gerado por culpa de alguma importação que eu tenha feito no programa.

O que eu quero saber é qual a causa deste erro e como posso solucioná-lo ?

Comment: Tem que instalar o runtime do visual C++. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/visual-cpp-build-tools/ está em pacotes redistribuíveis do Visual C++ tem que fazer o download de acordo com o processador da máquina.

Comment: @AugustoVasques então para que serve o `include_msvcr` ? Disseram que essa opção adiciona o Visual C++ ao gerar o .exe

Comment: Jean. Se não me engano essa opção de empacotar o runtime com o aplicativo deixou de funcionar a partir da versão 5 do cx_freeze não por depreciação mas por conta de um conjunto bugs que impedem dele empacotar o runtime. Você vai ter que vasculhar a lista [problemas](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues)  para conseguir um executável autossuficiente.

Comment: Achei essa resposta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103105/how-to-link-msvcr100-dll-to-cx-freeze-program espero que lhe ajude.